# How to use jasmine to mock window.click(event)

Tags: unit-testing, jasmine

I need to write a unit test for this function:

```
  public onClick(): void {
    $(window).click((event: any) => {
      if (event.target.href && event.target.href.search(/MOBWORKERMAP-/) !== -1) {
        this.buildCall('createPopup', event.target.href);
        this.setWindowLocation();
      }
    });
  }
```

I wonder how I can mock $(window).click, and pass an event to it?

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine spies are useful for mocking function calls. Here's Jasmine's spies documentation.

https://jasmine.github.io/api/2.6/global.html#spyOn

```
var spyEvent = spyOnEvent('#AN_ELEMENT', 'click')
$('#AN_ELEMENT').click()
expect('click').toHaveBeenTriggeredOn('#AN_Element')
```

Comment: Sorry, I wonder how I can update $(window).click((event:any)) `event`, because I have some condition is depended on `event`. `if (event.target.href && event.target.href.search(/MOBWORKERMAP-/) !== -1)`

Comment: I find a method to overwrite the standard event in $(window).click((event) => {}), juet use jQuery.event(). https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/